# Makefile with unlimited set of target files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a pipeline that looks like this:

```
json files
   image files
   audio files
       video files
```

The set of original json files is flexible, i.e. files can be added, edited, or deleted.

How do I set up makefile that will automatically create/update/remove video file when I add/edit/delete the respective json file?

This is the example makefile I've got so far

```
all: $(subst data,audio,$(subst .json,.mp3,$(wildcard target/*/data/*.json)))

%.mp3: %.json
    ./scripts/audio --json $<
```

Unfortunately the `%.mp3` doesn't match any of the prerequisites of `all`:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `target/main/audio/hello.mp3', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'll keep this abstract and high-level, since you've provided few details and no makefile.)

Creating and updating the video files is easy, it's the kind of job Make was designed for:

```
JSON_FILES := $(wildcard *.json)
VIDEO_TARGS := $(patsubst %.json,%.video,$(JSON_FILES))

%.video: %.json
    commands to use $< to build $@
```

Deleting obsolete video files is more awkward. There are several ways to do it; this may be the simplest:

```
EXTANT_VID := $(wildcard *.video)
OBSOLETE := $(filter-out $(VIDEO_TARGS),$(EXTANT_VID))

purge:
    rm -f $(OBSOLETE)
```